# Hotchocolate 13: Mutation does not work with schema first approach

Tags: c#, graphql, relayjs, hotchocolate

I am trying to use hotchocolate 13. I have declared a simple mutation as below and have used 'AddGlobalObjectIdentification' to configure relay schema.
I have used **schema first approach** and the mutation looks like below

SDL

```
type Mutation {
  updatePost(input: UpdatePostInput!): UpdatePostPayload!
}

input UpdatePostInput {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  tags: [PostTagInput!]!
}

type UpdatePostPayload {
  post: Post
  errors: [ApiError!]
}
```

and the API looks like below

```
[UseDbContext(typeof(ApiContext))]
public async Task<UpdatePostPayload> UpdatePostAsync(UpdatePostInput input,
                                                     [Service] ITopicEventSender eventSender,
                                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                                     ApiContext context)
{
....
}
```

with UpdatePostInput as below

```
public record UpdatePostInput([ID(nameof(Post))] int Id,
                              string Title,
                              string Content,
                              List<PostTagInput> Tags);
```

I was expecting that the mutation request should work

```
mutation($input: UpdatePostInput!) {
  updatePost(input: $input) {
    post{
      id
    }
  }
}

variables:
{
  "input": {
  "id": "UG9zdAppNA==",
  "title": "React",
   "content": "React is an awesome frontend technology.",
   "tags": []
  }
}
```

however I get the error "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.ToInt32'" for the 'id' field. **This works fine with the code first approach though. It also works fine with the 'Query'.**
Could anyone please suggest me if something is missing in my code or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public record UpdatePostInput([ID(nameof(Post))] int Id,
                          string Title,
                          string Content,
                          List<PostTagInput> Tags);
```

In this code you define Id as a integer. The correct type based on the error message you get is string. Try updating the code to let id be a string instead.